# Wordpress: custom walker for taxonomy terms

Tags: wordpress, categories, taxonomy

I need some help with a custom Wordpress navigation.

I have this walker that returns a list of categories, shows post count on each level but post links only on third level. So far, so good.

But how do I rewrite this for terms of a custom post type taxonomy? I already fiddled with get_terms instead of get_categories, but all I get is a blank screen.

Here's the code for the categories version that I am trying to rewrite (sorry, it's quite long):

```
<?php

add_filter( 'cat_index', 'return_cat_index' );

function return_cat_index()
{

$categories = get_categories( array(
  'orderby'    => 'name',
  'order'      => 'ASC',
  'parent'     => 0,
  'hide_empty' => false,
  'exclude'    => 1,
  'count'      => false
));

$return .= '<nav id="cat-index">';
$return .= '<ul class="menu">';
  foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    $subcats = get_categories( array(
      'parent'   => $category->cat_ID,
      'hide_empty' => false
    ));

  //count posts in category
  $count = 0;
  $taxonomy = 'category';
  $args = array(
    'child_of' => $category->cat_ID,
    );
  $tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy,$args);
  foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
    $count +=$tax_term->count;
    }

  //sprintf categories
  $return .= sprintf(
    '<li id="category-%1$s" class="toggle">%3$s <span class="post-count">' . $count . '</span><span class="cat-description">%5$s</span>',
    $category->cat_ID,
    get_category_link( $category->term_id ),
    $category->name,
    $category->category_count,
    $category->description
  );

  //if subcats are available
  if( $subcats ){
    $return .= sprintf(
      '<ul id="subCategories-%1$s">',
      $category->cat_ID
      );

    foreach ( $subcats as $subcat ) {
      $subsubcats = get_categories( array(
        'parent'   => $subcat->cat_ID,
        'hide_empty' => false
      ));

      //count posts in subcategory
      $countsub = 0;
      $taxonomy = 'category';
      $args = array(
        'child_of' => $subcat->cat_ID,
        );
      $tax_term_subs = get_terms($taxonomy,$args);
      foreach ($tax_term_subs as $tax_term_sub) {
        $countsub +=$tax_term_sub->count;
      }

      //sprintf subcats
      $return .= sprintf(
        '<li id="subCategory-%1$s" class="toggle">%3$s <span class="post-count">' . $countsub . '</span><span class="cat-description">%5$s</span>',
        $subcat->cat_ID,
        get_category_link( $subcat->cat_ID ),
        $subcat->name,
        $subcat->category_count,
        $subcat->description            
      );

      //if subsubcats are available
      if( $subsubcats ) {
        $return .= sprintf(
          '<ul id="subSubCategories-%s">', 
                      $subcat->cat_ID
                    );

                  foreach ( $subsubcats as $subsubcat ){

          //sprintf subsubcats
          $return .= sprintf(
            '<li id="subsubCategory-%1$s" class="toggle">%3$s <span class="post-count">%4$s</span><span class="cat-description">%5$s</span>',
            $subsubcat->cat_ID,
            get_category_link( $subsubcat->cat_ID ),
            $subsubcat->name,
            $subsubcat->category_count,
            $subsubcat->description
          );

          //print posts
          $the_query = new WP_Query(array( 'post_type' => 'bestpractices', 'cat' => $subsubcat->cat_ID )); ?>

          <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
            $return .= '<ul>';
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
              $return .= '<li><a class="link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>' . "\n";
            endwhile;
            $return .= '</ul>';

            wp_reset_postdata();

          else:
          endif;

                  }  

                $return .= '</ul>'; //end subsubcat ul
      }
      else{} //endif subsubcats

      $return .= '</li>'; //end subcat ul
    }

    $return .= '</ul>'; //end subcat ul
  }
  else{} //endif subcats

  $return .= '</li>'; //end category li
} //end for each category

$return .= '</ul>';
$return .= '</nav>';

return $return;
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance,

Georg

**Edit - updated code:**
I am rebuilding it from scratch which solved the blank screen problem. But the new code doesn't return any term_IDs which I use for nesting sub terms.

Any ideas?

```
add_filter( 'ap14-index', 'return_ap14_index' );

function return_ap14_index()
{

  $taxonomies = array( 
    'ap14',
  );

  $args = array(
    'orderby'           => 'name', 
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'        => false, 
    'exclude'           => array(), 
    'exclude_tree'      => array(), 
    'include'           => array(),
    'number'            => '',
    'fields'            => 'all',
    'slug'              => '',
    'parent'            => '',
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'child_of'          => 0,
    'get'               => '', 
    'name__like'        => '',
    'description__like' => '',
    'pad_counts'        => false,
    'offset'            => '',
    'search'            => '',
    'cache_domain'      => 'core'
  );

  $terms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);

  $return .= '<ul class="menu cat-index">';

     foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

       $subterms = get_terms( array(
        'parent'   => $term->term_id,
        'hide_empty' => false
        ));

       $return .= sprintf(
         '<li>%1$s',       
         $term->name
       );

       //if subterms are available
       if( $subterms ){
        $return .= sprintf(
          '<ul id="subTerms-%1$s">',
          $term->term_id
          );

        $return .= '</ul>'; //end subcat ul
      }


      $return .= '</li>'; //end category li
    } //end for each category

  $return .= '</ul>';

  return $return;
}
```

**Edit: updated again, sorry.**
Term_IDs are returning fine now, but still the sub terms don't show up. The output should be a nested list with sub terms being displayed within each parent terms li. But they just don't show and I think this bit of code doesn't work as expected:

```
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {         
  $subterms = get_terms( array(
    'parent'   => $term->term_id,
    'hide_empty' => false
  ));
}
```

Here's the complete code:

add_filter( 'cat_index', 'return_cat_index' );

```
function return_cat_index()
{

  $taxonomies = array( 
    'taxonomy_name',
  );

  $args = array(
    'orderby'           => 'name', 
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'        => false, 
    'exclude'           => array(), 
    'exclude_tree'      => array(), 
    'include'           => array(),
    'number'            => '',
    'fields'            => 'all',
    'slug'              => '',
    'parent'            => 0,
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'child_of'          => 0,
    'get'               => '', 
    'name__like'        => '',
    'description__like' => '',
    'pad_counts'        => false,
    'offset'            => '',
    'search'            => '',
    'cache_domain'      => 'core'    
  );

  $terms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);

  $return .= '<nav>';
  $return .= '<ul>';     

     foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

       $subterms = get_terms( array(
        'parent'   => $term->term_id,
        'hide_empty' => false
        ));

      //count posts in category
      $count = 0;
      $taxonomy = 'taxonomy_name';
      $args = array(
        'child_of' => $term->term_id,
        );
      $tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy,$args);
      foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
        $count +=$tax_term->count;
        }

       $return .= sprintf(
         '<li id="category-%1$s" class="toggle">%2$s <span class="post-count">' . $count . '</span><span class="cat-description">%3$s</span>',       
         $term->term_id,
         $term->name,
         $term->description
       );

       //if subcats are available
       if( $subterms ){
        $return .= sprintf(
          '<ul id="subTerm-%1$s">',
          $term->term_id
          );

          foreach ( $subterms as $subterm ) {
            $subsubterms = get_terms( array(
            'parent'   => $subterm->term_ID,
            'hide_empty' => false
          ));

          //count posts in subcategory
          $countsub = 0;
          $taxonomy = 'taxonomy_name';
          $args = array(
            'child_of' => $subterm->term_id,
            );
          $tax_term_subs = get_terms($taxonomy,$args);
          foreach ($tax_term_subs as $tax_term_sub) {
            $countsub +=$tax_term_sub->count;
          }

          //sprintf subcats
          $return .= sprintf(
            '<li id="subTerm-%1$s" class="toggle">%3$s <span class="post-count">' . $countsub . '</span><span class="cat-description">%5$s</span>',
            $subterm->term_id,
            get_category_link( $subterm->term_id ),
            $subterm->name,
            $subterm->category_count,
            $subterm->description            
          );

          //if subsubcats are available
          if( $subsubterms ) {
            $return .= sprintf(
              '<ul id="subSubTerms-%s">', 
                          $subterm->term_id
                        );

                      foreach ( $subsubterms as $subsubterm ){

              //sprintf subsubcats
              $return .= sprintf(
                '<li id="subsubTerm-%1$s" class="toggle">%3$s <span class="post-count">%4$s</span><span class="cat-description">%5$s</span>',
                $subsubterm->term_id,
                get_category_link( $subsubterm->term_id ),
                $subsubterm->name,
                $subsubterm->category_count,
                $subsubterm->description
              );

              //print posts
              $the_query = new WP_Query(array( 'post_type' => 'bestpractices', 'cat' => $subsubterm->term_id )); ?>

              <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
                $return .= '<ul>';
                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
                  $return .= '<li><a class="link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>' . "\n";
                endwhile;
                $return .= '</ul>';

                wp_reset_postdata();

              else:
              endif;                  
              }  

            $return .= '</ul>'; //end subsubcat ul
          }
          else{} //endif subsubcats

          $return .= '</li>'; //end subcat ul
        }

        $return .= '</ul>'; //end subcat ul
      }
      else{} //endif subcats

      $return .= '</li>'; //end category li
    } //end for each category

    $return .= '</ul>';  
    $return .= '</nav>';

  return $return;
}
```

Comment: Do you have some *error_log*?

Comment: Have you tried passing "taxonomy" parameter to `get_categories`?

Comment: @Anand thanks for you're reply. Tried that, but it gave me a blank screen, so the error must have been elsewhere.

Comment: @pbaldauf thanks for reply. I am rebuilding it from scratch and now it works. I edited my original post, because the new code doesn't return any term_IDs.